# Merge query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    ModelCode_PFN AS ModelCode
    , B.Name_N AS ModelName
    , OriginMaterial_FN AS OriginMaterial
    , CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN C.PartNumber_N END AS OriginPartNo
    , CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN Property_N END AS OriginProperty
    , CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN Vender_N END AS OriginVender
    , MaterialCode_PFN AS AltMaterial
    , A.PartNumber_N AS AltPartNo
    , CASE WHEN MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU THEN Property_N END AS AltProperty
    , CASE WHEN MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU THEN Vender_N END AS AltVender
FROM 
    NBOM AS A WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    NModel AS B WITH(NOLOCK) ON ModelCode_PFN = B.Code_PNU
INNER JOIN 
    NMaterial AS C WITH(NOLOCK) ON (OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU OR MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU) 
WHERE 
    OriginMaterial_FN = '0RHAA-0211A'
```

When using this query, result is two rows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7YEm.png)

After joining one table, I want to get the result of two conditions in one row.

How to merge this result into one row?

I tried `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but it is not working.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Maybe look into `GROUP BY`

Comment: When you say "I tried DISTINCT and Group By but it is not working" you actually need to show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide what the rules are to enable a "merge" of information into one row. A very typical way to do this is to use the maximum value of those columns that one value and one NULL. But, if there is more than one non-null value in a column this might not be be the best option, we cannot make that decision for you.

With that said, the simplest way is to group the data, and use the max() function e.g:

```
SELECT
      ModelCode_PFN AS ModelCode
    , B.Name_N AS ModelName
    , OriginMaterial_FN AS OriginMaterial
    , max(CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN C.PartNumber_N END) AS OriginPartNo
    , max(CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN Property_N END) AS OriginProperty
    , max(CASE WHEN OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU THEN Vender_N END) AS OriginVender
    , MaterialCode_PFN AS AltMaterial
    , A.PartNumber_N AS AltPartNo
    , max(CASE WHEN MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU THEN Property_N END) AS AltProperty
    , max(CASE WHEN MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU THEN Vender_N END) AS AltVender
FROM NBOM AS A
INNER JOIN NModel AS B
    ON ModelCode_PFN = B.Code_PNU
INNER JOIN NMaterial AS C 
    ON (OriginMaterial_FN = C.Code_PNU OR MaterialCode_PFN = C.Code_PNU) 
WHERE OriginMaterial_FN = '0RHAA-0211A'
GROUP BY
      ModelCode_PFN
    , B.Name_N
    , OriginMaterial_FN
    , MaterialCode_PFN
    , A.PartNumber_N
```

**nb** the columns that you include in the group by clause are the "non-aggregating" columns i.e. they do NOT need or use "aggregate functions" such as max/min/avg etc.

Other notes.

- Joins **multiply** rows. So it can be a whole lot more efficient to group data BEFORE joining it to other tables.
- use the table aliases in all of the column references, we have no idea which table owns what columns (except where you have used the table aliases).